# Set an argument as a property of a method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a function where I can pass in the type of toastr and the message, although I can solve this problem by making a big if else statement

```
if (type == 'success') {
  toastr.success('Profile URL Copied!');
} else if (type == 'info') {
  toastr.info('Profile URL Copied!');
}
```

etc. Can I pass in the argument straight to a property

```
function toasterMsg(type, msg) {

    toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": false,
    "debug": false,
    "newestOnTop": false,
    "progressBar": false,
    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
    "preventDuplicates": false,
    "onclick": null,
    "showDuration": "300",
    "hideDuration": "1000",
    "timeOut": "5000",
    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
    "showEasing": "swing",
    "hideEasing": "linear",
    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}

    toastr. THE TYPE HERE ('Profile URL Copied!');

}
```

Comment: `toastr[type](msg)` should do...

Comment: Yes. See this article on property [Propert Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

In your case you can do toastr[type](msg).

Answer (score 1):

If you status and the function name are **the same**, you can call like:

```
toastr[ type ]( 'Profile URL Copied!' );
```

Here is a fiddle:

```js
function toastr() {
  this.success = function(text) {
    console.log("success", text);
  }

  this.info = function(text) {
    console.log("info", text);
  }
}


var toastr = new toastr;

toastr['info']('Profile URL Copied!');
toastr['success']('Profile URL Copied2!');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `type` variable to access the method as you would access the property of any object:

```
function toasterMsg(type, msg) {

  toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": false,
    [...]
  };

  // Check that toastr.[type] is indeed a function
  if (toastr[type] && typeof toastr[type] === "function") {
    toastr[type]('Profile URL Copied!');
  }
}
```